# What is this device RV1 that looks like antiparallel diodes across the input of a bridge rectifier?

Tags: identification, components

This is the initial part part of a 10 V power supply circuit from a 1970s (or perhaps early 1980s) chain printer. What is RV1 and what does it do?

[image: RV1]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It  is a [Metal Oxide Varistor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varistor) (MOV) that is used to absorb transient energy. Such devices have a decreasing resistance with voltage and are not polarity-sensitive. They do not have the negative resistance (avalanche) characteristic of the diac which would probably be destructive in this application. The modern symbol is this:

[image]

However the diac-like symbol was used in past (from American National Standard,Graphic Symbols for Electrical and Electronics Diagrams, ANSI Y32.2-1975 p.27):

[image]

The designator VR is more commonly used than RV for varistors in modern times.

Comment: Wouldn't a diac reset as the AC current comes back to zero in this application? Would the high current flowing for a short time during the waveform's return to zero be a problem? Wouldn't the worst case just be that the fuse is blown?

Comment: @cjs Diacs are not intended for high current. It would definitely fail (probably short) and then the fuse would blow.

Answer (score 0):

The symbol of RV1 is that of a Diac: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.shutterstock.com/image-vector/symbol-diac-electronic-1965056218).

And functionally, it could be a Diac i.e. when an over-voltage occurs, the Diac will clamp the line and either blow the fuse or reset on the next AC cycle.

However, Diacs tend not to be rated at such a high withstand voltage (greater than the peaks of 341 volts AC) so, I suspect it may be trying to represent a gas-discharge tube or maybe an MOV.

Comment: It's 34.1V AC, corresponding to a peak amplitude of about 50V.

Answer (score 0):

The symbol is that of a [DIAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIAC) and these have a breakdown voltage which, when exceeded, causes the DIAC to conduct and remain in conduction mode until the current falls below the hold-on value.

In this case it is wired across the AC input to the bridge. If a transient voltage arrives the DIAC will conduct, suppressing the transient, until the next zero-cross of the mains.

I don't know why they have chosen the component designator "RV".